# cannot copy results from device allocated memory to host SYCL unified shared memory

Tags: c++, sycl

I'm new to SYCL and trying to run very simple vector addition program using ComputeCpp.

```
#include <sycl/sycl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class vector_addition;
class vector_initialization;


int main() {
    constexpr int size = 10;

    try {
        cl::sycl::queue queue(cl::sycl::gpu_selector{});

        int *result_device = cl::sycl::malloc_device<int>(size , queue);
        int *vec1 = cl::sycl::malloc_shared<int>(size , queue);
        int *vec2 = cl::sycl::malloc_shared<int>(size , queue);


        queue.submit([&](cl::sycl::handler &cgh) {
            cgh.parallel_for<vector_initialization>(
                    size, [=](cl::sycl::id<1> idx) {
                        vec1[idx[0]] = idx[0];
                        vec2[idx[0]] = idx[0] * 2;
                    });
        });
        queue.wait();

        //std::cout << "vec1[1] = " << vec1[1] << std::endl;

        queue.submit([&](cl::sycl::handler &cgh) {
            cgh.parallel_for<class vector_addition>(
                size, [=](cl::sycl::id<1> idx) {
                    result_device[idx[0]] = vec1[idx[0]] + vec2[idx[0]];
                });
        });
        queue.wait();

        int result[size];

        queue.submit([&](cl::sycl::handler &cgh) {
            cgh.memcpy(result, result_device, size * sizeof(int));
        });
        queue.wait();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            std::cout << result[i] << " ";

    }
    catch (cl::sycl::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "SYCL exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As one can see, 3 arrays are being allocated using USM. The program runs without any errors, but `cgh.memcpy` seems not to copy the results back to the host.
The output is:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

However, it runs perfectly on host device:

```
0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27
```

Also, if the line `//std::cout << "vec1[1] = " << vec1[1] << std::endl;` is uncommented I get the `segmentation fault` which, I believe, should not happend when accessing shared memory on host.

Here's the output of `computecpp_info`:

```
********************************************************************************

ComputeCpp Info (CE 2.11.0 2022/08/08)

SYCL 1.2.1 revision 3

********************************************************************************


Device Info:

Discovered 1 devices matching:
  platform    : <any>
  device type : <any>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Device 0:

  Device is supported                     : UNTESTED - Untested OS
  Bitcode targets                         : spirv64 ptx64 
  CL_DEVICE_NAME                          : NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU
  CL_DEVICE_VENDOR                        : NVIDIA Corporation
  CL_DRIVER_VERSION                       : 525.116.03
  CL_DEVICE_TYPE                          : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU 

If you encounter problems when using any of these OpenCL devices, please consult
this website for known issues:
https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/platform-support?version=2.11.0

********************************************************************************
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi! Your code appears to be correct and it works correctly with the [oneAPI for CUDA](https://codeplay.com/solutions/oneapi/for-cuda/), which [has superseded ComputeCPP on NVIDIA devices in 2020](https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/2.11.0/guides/platform-support-notes/computecpp-with-ptx-for-nvidia-devices). Have you tried using it instead of ComputeCPP?